# TokenAccountNotFoundError when sending SPL tokens in React

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account

When I try to send my SPL tokens I get this error:

```
OrderRow.js:72 TokenAccountNotFoundError
at unpackAccount (account.ts:170:1)
at getAccount (account.ts:103:1)
at async getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount (getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts:79:1)
at async transferTokens (OrderRow.js:39:1)
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection, 
  fromPublicKey,
  tokenPublicKey,
  fromPublicKey,
  signTransaction
);
const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  fromPublicKey,
  tokenPublicKey,
  toPublicKey,
  signTransaction
);
const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
  createTransferInstruction(
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    fromPublicKey,
    parseInt(amount * Math.pow(10, 9)), 
    [],
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  )
);
```

It fails in the toTokenAccount function

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

`getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` takes a `Signer` as the second parameter, since it might require paying for the new account's rent. The first one succeeds because the account already exists, but the second one fails because it doesn't.  Assuming you have `fromKeypair`, the keypair for `fromPublicKey`, you should do:

```
const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  fromKeypair,
  tokenPublicKey,
  toPublicKey,
  signTransaction
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got that error and have spent way too much time debugging. Annoyingly, I reused code from previous tests that seemed to work fine. This is extracted from unit tests, rather than frontend but someone might find it useful.

Throws `TokenAccountNotFoundError`:

```
const payerKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const payer = payerKeypair.publicKey;

const adminKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const admin = payer.publicKey; // ERROR: leads to TokenAccountNotFoundError
let adminATA;

const user1Keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const user1 = user1Keypair.publicKey;
let user1ATA;

mintSC = await createMint(
  connection,
  mintAuthSC,
  mintAuthSC.publicKey,
  mintAuthSC.publicKey,
  10
);

[adminATA, user1ATA] = await Promise.all([
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    adminKeypair,
    mintSC,
    admin
  ),
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    user1Keypair,
    mintSC,
    user1
  ),
]);
```

Working (for now) code:

```
const payerKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const payer = payerKeypair.publicKey;

const adminKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const admin = adminKeypair.publicKey; // Set to the correct Pubkey
let adminATA;

const user1Keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
const user1 = user1Keypair.publicKey;
let user1ATA;

mintSC = await createMint(
  connection,
  mintAuthSC,
  mintAuthSC.publicKey,
  mintAuthSC.publicKey,
  10
);    

// Removed await Promise.all
adminATA =  await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  adminKeypair,
  mintSC,
  admin
);
user1ATA = getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  user1Keypair,
  mintSC,
  user1
);
```

What still surprises me is that this error occurs even with correct keypair/address pair but with the single `await` using `Promise.all`. Before the tests had `await Promise.all([` to save time, but this time around unless each item was awaited for it would also crash with `TokenAccountNotFoundError`.